# Create a sequence based on factor level's length in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using R right now and I am trying to create a new column "c" with a sequence dependent on the length of column "a" factor level. I have the example the before and after example. I am having trouble creating the "after" table. Can anyone help?

```
BEFORE
    a b
    1 hi
    1 hello
    1 howdy
    1 hola
    2 world
    2 world
    3 something
    3 someone

AFTER    
    a b          c
    1 hi         1
    1 hello      2
    1 howdy      3
    1 hola       4
    2 world      1
    2 world      2
    3 something  1 
    3 someone    2
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this in `base R`

```
df1$c <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(a), a, FUN=seq_along))
```

Or

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(df1, 'a')[]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(c = seq(a))

  a         b c
1 1        hi 1
2 1     hello 2
3 1     howdy 3
4 1      hola 4
5 2     world 1
6 2     world 2
7 3 something 1
8 3   someone 2
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, c := seq(.N), by=a]
```